# How to exit infinite while loop with KeyboardInterrupt

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have an infinite while loop that doesn't exit when I raise the KeyboardInterrupt exception. This is my code.

```
try:
    data = client.service.Read(name)
    b = []
    b.append(data.Item[0].UCPTlastUpdate)
    while True:
        data = client.service.Read(name)
        j = data.Item[0].UCPTvalue[0].value
        c = data.Item[0].UCPTlastUpdate
        if b[0] != c:
            b.pop(0)
            b.append(c)
            print j,c
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    sys.exit()
```

Comment: You don't raise it explicitly in your code. Better press `Ctrl + C` when your code runs.

Comment: I press Ctrl + D and nothing happens code continues running. I'm using sublime text 2.

Comment: @thefourtheye -- `Ctrl + d` sends the EOF character to a stream -- `Ctrl + c` is what generally sends SIGINT (or equivalent).

Comment: It could hang if `client.service.Read` is handling the `KeyboardInterrupt` -- In that case, you need to fix the problem in that function/method.

Comment: @user2769651 You should not execute any program which accepts input from user in sublime. It should be done in console.

Comment: Ive tried the mac equivalent of both of these commands with no luck.

Comment: @user2769651 -- It's still Ctrl + c on a mac ... Also, I agree with thefourtheye.  Have you tried running it from console and interrupting it there?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification, it works with console. It would be easier though if it worked with sublime text as well :/